# Android/ChromeCast: Trigger current media to pause

Tags: android, google-cast

The problem I am trying to solve:

> When receiving phone calls, I am unable to pause playback before
>   answering the call.

The new chromecast app has a generic pause action, which works on the apps I tested. Ideally, I would like to make a widget/app that triggers the pause in the same manner for a specified chromecast.

I have been looking into the sender/receiver app model and documentation, however, I can't seem to find something as seamless as the Device list in the new ChromeCast app. (which allows for pausing without explicitly connecting beforehand).

1. Does anyone know if I can send a pause event to the chromecast app?
2. If not, does anyone have a suggestion on how to access devices similar to that as the chromecast app's device list?

I tried Tasker's auto-input and auto-cast and media utilities, but they are unable to pause Netflix or Pandora on my device.

Device: Samsung Galaxy S4
Android: 5.0.1

Thank you, Steven

Comment: I don't think it's possible (yet). See [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chromecast/sBydiL-hxrU/vZmZxNYL_zMJ). That functionality might be exposed in the future, but who knows.

Comment: Yea, but that is a year old and there has been a new API and chromecast app since then